# FindViewById in a non activity class

Tags: java, android

How can I use `findViewById()` in a non activity class. Below is my code snippet. I get the error message: "can't resolve method findViewById" if used directly. And if i try to use the class constructor (Where the imageView is available) i get this error "cannot resolve symbol context"

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends FirstBroadcastReceiver {

Activity activity;
public MyBroadcastReceiver(Context context, Activity activity){
    this.context=context;     // error here(cannot resolve symbol context)
    this.activity=activity;
}

    @Override
    protected void (Context context) {
    // content
    }

    @Override
    public void onButton(Context context, boolean isClick) {

        if(isClick) {

    ImageView blueImage = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    blueImage.setColorFilter(0xff000000);
         }
    }
.......
....
    // and so on
```

And below is my MainActivity with MybroadcastReceiver class instance.Is it correct?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     // and so on
    }
}


MyBroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(MainActivity.this,this);

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult() {
  // some code
  }

@Override
     public void onInitialized(MyManager manager){
 // some code   
 }
```

Comment: What is your context parameter? If it is Activity, you can cast it to Activity and call findViewById, otherwise you can't

Comment: Wait, what is `Receiver`? I'm guessing you mean `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: yes it is BroadcastReciever

Comment: i also tried to make a function in main activity and use it in my broadcast but then it gives me this error "static method cannot be referenced from a static context" anyway around that?

Comment: Tell me what exactly u trying to do with broadcast receiver coz I c u trying to set a button on it. What is it doing, tell in brief so any could be done

Comment: I am extendng a broadcast receiver library from another project and using its function onclick to change the color of a imageview e.g from blue to black e.t.c...and this onclick is already defined in that library  so just have to change the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

A `BroacastReceiver` runs entirely in the background, listening for Intents sent either by the OS or other apps. It is not responsible for any UI interactions, and cannot access any views. Therefore, `findViewById` cannot be used within a BroadcastReceiver.

See also - [What is BroadcastReceiver and when we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296987/what-is-broadcastreceiver-and-when-we-use-it)

Comment: i also tried to make a function in main activity and use it in my broadcast but then it gives me this error "static method cannot be referenced from a static context" anyway around that?

Comment: One thing to note: `BroadcastReceiver`s run on the main thread for your app, not on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass View to the non activity class, before using findViewByid
and
try using

```
view.findViewByid(R.id.view_id);
```

Comment: its not working error msg "cannot resolve symbol view" and as mentioned previously by other guysi cannot directly use findViewbyid in BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: It will not work for Broadcast receiver, because broadcast Receiver can even work when view is null.

You must change approach or try using callback mechanism

Comment: how do i use callback ...when i tried to make function in main activity and use it in my broadcast then it gives me this error "static method cannot be referenced from a static context" anyway around that

Answer (score 0):

Because `context` is `null` in `Broadcast` class. use `Broadcast` class constructor to pass `parent_activity(Where the imageView is available)` context in `Broadcast` to access the context:

```
public class Broadcast extends BroadCastReceiver {

Activity activity;
public Broadcast(Context context,Activity activity){
this.context=context;
this.activity=activity;
}
 .......
    ....... //so on
```

and in `parent_activity` create `Broadcast` class instance by passing `parent_activity` context as:

```
Broadcast broadcast = new Broadcast(parent_activity.this,this);
```

Use `activity` instance as:

```
@Override
public void onButton(Context context, boolean isClick) {

    if(isClick) {
       ImageView blueImage = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView);  //<--- here
     }
}
 .........
      ......... //so on
```

Comment: I tried using your code but now my app crashes...i think its because of the class instance i am using from main activity?

Comment: when i use this.context = context it gives me error 'cannot resolve symbol context' .. i will also upload the full code